# it shows an oval during animation but not a circle(iOS)

Tags: ios, animation, cabasicanimation

I want to use CABasicAnimation to draw a circle, but strangely it shows an oval during animation
the code is as following:

```
 //---------------draw circle
// Set up the shape of the circle
int radius = 10;
CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
// Make a circular shape
circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 ,self.view.frame.size.height/2) radius:radius startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI*2 clockwise:NO].CGPath;
// Configure the apperence of the circle
circle.fillColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
circle.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
circle.lineWidth = 1;
// Add to parent layer
[self.view.layer addSublayer:circle];
// Configure animation
CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
[pathAnimation setFromValue:(id)[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 ,self.view.frame.size.height/2) radius:0 startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI*2 clockwise:NO].CGPath];
[pathAnimation setToValue:(id)[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 ,self.view.frame.size.height/2) radius:radius*1.2 startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI*2 clockwise:NO].CGPath];
[pathAnimation setDuration:15.0f];
[pathAnimation setRepeatCount:1.0f];
[pathAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]];
circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height/2) radius:radius startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI*2 clockwise:NO].CGPath;
[circle addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"changePathAnimation"];
```

How can I deal with it.

Comment: what do u want to achieve from this code... ?

Comment: I want to draw a round dynamically. but strangely it shows an oval during animation @Spynet

Comment: CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    [pathAnimation setFromValue:(id)[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 ,self.view.frame.size.height/2) radius:10 startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI*2 clockwise:NO].CGPath];
 try this

Comment: I just modified the start radius to 0.1, it works @Spynet

Comment: is that working fine or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like that,

```
CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
[pathAnimation setFromValue:(id)[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 ,self.view.frame.size.height/2) radius:10 startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI*2 clockwise:NO].CGPath];
[pathAnimation setToValue:(id)[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 ,self.view.frame.size.height/2) radius:radius*1.2 startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI*2 clockwise:NO].CGPath];
[pathAnimation setDuration:15.0f];
[pathAnimation setRepeatCount:1.0f];
[pathAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]];
circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height/2) radius:radius startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI*2 clockwise:NO].CGPath;
[circle addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"changePathAnimation"];
```

Comment: But I want to get the circle radius started from 0

Comment: I have resolved it by setting the start radius value to 0.1, thank you very much.